# Define a empty Collection attribute for Spring Bean

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

How can i define an empty collection for a variable in the bean declaration?

Ex:

```
beans {

importadorContrato(ImportadorContrato) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'prototype'
    bean.initMethod = 'init'
    bean.destroyMethod = 'destroy'
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    listaErros = []
    contratosImportados = [:]
}}
```

the problem is, properties listaErros and contratosImporados always stay with the same reference.

As a work around, i defined a initMethod and initialed the fields there, but i would like spring doing it for me.

Comment: Can you just define two different beans and then use `ref()` to point to them?

Comment: Thx @GregPotter! It sure worked, but there isn't another way? Normally i would define in a xml file <list></list> and <map></map> and i would get the same thing, do you know if it's possible in grails?